# Pesquisar dois números de uma só vez

Tags: mysql

Talvez essa pergunta até tenha sido respondida já, mas eu não sei como fazê-la, e caí no tipico problema XY.

Tenho uma tabela que tem vários ids, e preciso pesquisar dois id's, 34 e 5.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc7cef/1)

No caso acima, criei exatamente o que trará na minha tabela, só que preciso que apenas traga informação quando tiver os dois números 34 e 5 na mesma transação, e não apenas um. Então neste caso o IN não funcionou.

Segue estrutura da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE IDS (
    IDTRANSACTIONS INT,
    IDSUBSTATUS INT
);

INSERT INTO IDS (IDTRANSACTIONS, IDSUBSTATUS)
VALUES (12548, 1),
(12548, 5),
(12548, 34),
(12548, 6),
(12548, 3),
(48754, 1),
(48754, 5),
(48754, 32),
(48754, 3),
(48754, 1),
(48754, 6)
```

E o select que estou fazendo:

```
select * from ids where idsubstatus in (34,5)
```

e o resultado que está trazendo:

```
IDTRANSACTIONS  IDSUBSTATUS
12548           5
12548           34
48754           5
```

A IDTRANSACTION 12548 está correta, mas a 48754 não. :)

Comment: Você quer o `IDTRANSACTIONS` que tenha pelo menos uma linha com `IDSUBSTATUS` 34 e outra com `IDSUBSTATUS` 5? Isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Tem que ter os dois idsubstatus. As duas linhas (34 e 5) ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @LaylaComparin Você que retornar duas vezes o `12548` ou somente uma vez?

Comment: Da forma que está no resultado, mas como o 48754  não tem o 34, não quero que traga ele. Pra mim o importante é vir as duas linhas na mesma transação (34 e 5). Se vier só uma linha, no caso o exemplo da 48754 está errado. Não tem importância o IDTRANSACTIONS  12548 vir repetido. :)

Comment: É isso aqui o que você quer? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc7cef/21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você fazendo um `INNER JOIN` buscando pelo `idtransactions` e pelo número procurado em `idsubstatus` obrigará o `SELECT` à retornar somente os itens que tem os dois números:

```
SELECT a.idtransactions
FROM ids a
INNER JOIN ids b ON a.idtransactions = b.idtransactions AND b.idsubstatus = 34
INNER JOIN ids c ON a.idtransactions = c.idtransactions AND c.idsubstatus = 5
WHERE a.idsubstatus in (34, 5);
```

> O `WHERE` fará com que não seja retornadas nenhuma linha que não tenha
>   o `idsubstatus` igual à 5 ou 34;

No formato acima, será retornado duas vezes o `idtransactions` `12548`, mas você pode trazer somente uma vez agrupando o resultado:

```
SELECT a.idtransactions
FROM ids a
INNER JOIN ids b ON a.idtransactions = b.idtransactions AND b.idsubstatus = 34
INNER JOIN ids c ON a.idtransactions = c.idtransactions AND c.idsubstatus = 5
GROUP BY a.idtransactions;
```

Veja mais sobre `JOIN` [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma de fazer, seria utilizando `HAVING COUNT` em *subquery*. Desta forma, você não fica presa em somente 2 valores ( `34,5` ), podendo passar mais parâmetros:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ids
WHERE idsubstatus IN (34,5)
AND idtransactions IN (SELECT idtransactions
FROM ids
WHERE idsubstatus IN (34,5)
GROUP BY idtransactions
HAVING COUNT(idtransactions) = 2)
```

Resultado:

[image: 01]

---

Ou caso queria trazer somente o `idtransactions`:

```
SELECT idtransactions, GROUP_CONCAT(idsubstatus) AS idsubstatus
FROM IDS
WHERE idsubstatus IN (34,5)
GROUP BY idtransactions
HAVING COUNT(idtransactions) = 2
```

Resultado:

[image: 02]

---

Como no seu exemplo, mas trazendo todos os status do registro filtrado:

```
SELECT idtransactions, GROUP_CONCAT(idsubstatus) AS idsubstatus
FROM ids
WHERE idtransactions IN (SELECT idtransactions
FROM ids
WHERE idsubstatus IN (34,5)
GROUP BY idtransactions
HAVING COUNT(idtransactions) = 2)
GROUP BY idtransactions
```

Resultado:

[image: 03]

Observe que no `HAVING COUNT` você terá que setar a quantidade total de itens em sua condição `idsubstatus IN (34,5)`.

---

Usando *subquery*:

```
SELECT idtransactions, GROUP_CONCAT(idsubstatus)
FROM ids
WHERE idtransactions IN
  (SELECT idtransactions FROM ids WHERE idsubstatus = 34)
AND idtransactions IN
  (SELECT idtransactions FROM ids WHERE idsubstatus = 5)
GROUP BY idtransactions;
```

Resultado:

[image: 04]

---

### Veja funcionando no [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4LnsMdKAjWFwZbRF1qWimn/0)

---

## Referências

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

[HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: Tem um caso que dá um "falso positivo", que é quando tem 2 registros com o mesmo idTransaction e idSubStatus: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d46d3/6 - mas a ideia do `count` é boa, desde que garanta que não vai ter esses registros repetidos. +1 :)

Comment: @hkotsubo Verdade! Porque não é `PK`. Mas pela ideia/estrutura, esse campo deveria ser `PK`, né!? hahaha

Comment: Só pelo exemplo, não dá pra saber. Mas de fato, é razoável assumir que em produção deve existir uma tabela de status e esse campo é PK. Acho que fui pedante demais... :-)

Comment: Normal! Já acostuma pensar nos possíveis problemas! rs Já já vejo o seu SQLFiddle. Está muito ruim o servidor dos caras.